# CLLocationManagerDelegate Singleton

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a `CLLocationManager` Singleton with this interface only `Location.start()` on `ViewController` but I don't see any location updates with this structure.
 I am using `print(mostRecentLocation)` to detect a location update. 
 How can I fix this?

Here is my code in `Location.swift`:

```
import CoreLocation

class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private static var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
        var manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        return manager
    }()

    static func start() {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
          return
        }

        print(mostRecentLocation)
    }
}
```

And on `ViewController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Location.start()
}
```

I see this https://github.com/igroomgrim/CLLocationManager-Singleton-in-Swift 
 and this https://github.com/irfanlone/CLLocationManager-Singleton-Swift 
 but I don't like the interface.

Comment: and where is your singleton...?

Answer (score 10):

Somewhere you have to set the delegate of the location manager.

Anyway a singleton is supposed to be a (shared) **instance** of a class so I recommend something like this

```
class Radar: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = Radar()

    let locationManager : CLLocationManager

    override init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func start() {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        print(mostRecentLocation)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

---

And call it

```
Radar.shared.start()
```

---

To get your desired syntax use a class wrapper with a class method

```
class Location {

    static func start() {
        Radar.shared.start()
    }
}
```

then you can write

```
Location.start()
```

Comment: how i can set delegate with this interface `Location.setDelegate(self)` and use only `Location.start()` without `shared`?

Comment: Class methods are not a *singleton*. What's wrong with the shared instance?

Comment: I see the Radar.io documentation (https://radar.io/documentation/sdk) and i see `Radar.setDelegate(self)` and `Radar.startTracking()` i want to understand how I can create this type of interface. :)

Comment: You need the shared instance anyway. I updated the answer to show you a way to use the class based syntax. I'm sure `Radar` uses a similar pattern

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Create a Location manager Single Tone **FLocationManager.swift** and copy paste below snippet there in swift 4.1:-

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


class FLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let shared = FLocationManager()
    let locationManager : CLLocationManager
    var locationInfoCallBack: ((_ info:LocationInformation)->())!

    override init() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func start(locationInfoCallBack:@escaping ((_ info:LocationInformation)->())) {
        self.locationInfoCallBack = locationInfoCallBack
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stop() {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
            return
        }
        print(mostRecentLocation)
        let info = LocationInformation()
        info.latitude = mostRecentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        info.longitude = mostRecentLocation.coordinate.longitude


        //now fill address as well for complete information through lat long ..
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(mostRecentLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
            guard let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first else { return }
            if let city = placemark.locality,
                let state = placemark.administrativeArea,
                let zip = placemark.postalCode,
                let locationName = placemark.name,
                let thoroughfare = placemark.thoroughfare,
                let country = placemark.country {
                info.city     = city
                info.state    = state
                info.zip = zip
                info.address =  locationName + ", " + (thoroughfare as String)
                info.country  = country
            }
            self.locationInfoCallBack(info)
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

class LocationInformation {
    var city:String?
    var address:String?
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees?
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees?
    var zip:String?
    var state :String?
    var country:String?
    init(city:String? = "",address:String? = "",latitude:CLLocationDegrees? = Double(0.0),longitude:CLLocationDegrees? = Double(0.0),zip:String? = "",state:String? = "",country:String? = "") {
        self.city    = city
        self.address = address
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.zip        = zip
        self.state = state
        self.country = country
    }
}
```

> 2. Add Permission request in your Application Info.plist(Right Click and select option open as "Source Code") file:-

[image]

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

> 3.Use Single Tone location manager  in your any UIViewController and stop anywhere you want.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //use below code snippet for your single tone location manager class in entire app where ever you want 
        FLocationManager.shared.start { (info) in
            print(info.longitude ?? 0.0)
            print(info.latitude ?? 0.0)
            print(info.address ?? "")
            print(info.city ?? "")
            print(info.zip ?? "")
        }

    }
```

> 4. For stop location manager service in your app you have to use this :-

```
   FLocationManager.shared.stop()
```

**Cheers !!! Happy Coding  :)**

Comment: I tested the code , every time called   FLocationManager.shared.start  , will need to call  FLocationManager.shared.start  in the completion handler , otherwise , it will not update the LocationInformation .

Comment: @Richard thank you for commenting.  FLocationManager.shared.start  i placed in viewDidLoad() just because of testing. You need to call it in a seperate place so from that you can get only updated result rather than placing it on viewDidLoad function itself. Here in viewDidLoad() function also it will give you only updated result once location will update.

Comment: Sorry for my typo , I was supposed to mean every time called FLocationManager.shared.start , will need to call FLocationManager.shared.STOP in the completion handler , otherwise , it will not update next time when you call FLocationManager.shared.start again .

Comment: @RichardMao yeah bro! that's why we gave FLocationManager.shared.stop() , you may use where ever you want to stop location service in entire application as well rather than completion handler only. :)

Comment: then I suggest change "locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest" to "locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters" , latter one takes much less time and prior
 one some time impact my UI while waiting for the callback information .

Comment: This depends on user requirement , so if you want location update in only kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters then you can use that one.

Comment: I think you simply should remove `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` from `start` method, and call it every time you need..

Comment: @MuratAkdeniz It's very nice of you :)